# What does the callback .ops stands for?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working with this Node.js express app

```
const db = mongoskin.db('mongodb://@localhost:27017/test')
const id = mongoskin.helper.toObjectID
```

Post method

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', (req, res, next) => {
    pino(req,res);
    req.log.info('pino output');
    req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, (e, results) => {
      if (e) return next(e)
      res.send(results.ops)
    })
})
```

What does the .ops actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by looking at console.log(results)

```
{
  result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
  ops: [
    {
      name: 'richard',
      email: 'ricard@gmail.com',
      _id: 5e9feb03b73a9464635bc328
    }
  ],
  insertedCount: 1,
  insertedIds: [ 5e9feb03b73a9464635bc328 ]
}
```

We will send only ops elements to MongoDB.